# sinon mocking GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods assertions fail everytime. no idea why

Tags: node.js, sinon, nodeunit

am learning sinon and nodeUnit for nodejs. wrote simple [module](https://github.com/MHDuke/nodeJs/blob/master/modules/http-module.js) that handles GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods.

then started writing unit test. Now there are two sides for my problem:

One being: in [`GET` test](https://github.com/MHDuke/nodeJs/blob/master/unit-testing-intro/test-http-module.js)  when i specify `requestMock.method = 'GET';` then
run `nodeunit test-http-module.js` test fails, when reviewing call stack it says POST request failed (handlePostRequest as highlighted in call stack below).

Two being: when changing `requestMock.method = 'GET';` to `'POST', 'PUT' or 'DELETE'` test still fails no matter what i change! but in latter cases the call stack shows the correct method being directed to.

I think there is a single problem causing the continuous failures and that `GET` being directed to `POST`.

please explain what is wrong.

> ExpectationError: Unexpected call: writeHead(200, { Content-Type:
>   "text/plain" })
>
> Expectation met: writeHead(200, { Content-Type: "text/plain" }[, ...]) once
>
> at Object.fail (D:\Projects\node-book\node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\mock-expectation.js:281:25)
>
> at Object.invokeMethod (D:\Projects\node-book\node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\mock.js:174:25)
>
> at Object.writeHead (D:\Projects\node-book\node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\mock.js:67:35)
>
> at `handlePostRequest` (D:\Projects\node-book\modules\http-module.js:8:14)
>
> at Object.handleRequest (D:\Projects\node-book\modules\http-module.js:34:26)
>
> at Object.exports.handleGetRequestTest (D:\Projects\node-book\unit-testing-intro\test-http-module.js:22:21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing `break;` statements in the cases of your `switch`.